# Can't create app packages Universal Apps

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I wanted to load my universal windows app into the app store. So i create my app packages. The problem was now, that i got a few build errors that the namespace of my custom control cannot be found. This is interesting because I can start my app in debug and release mode on my computer and on my mobile.

I hope you know what my problem is and you can help me.

Comment: Have you modified anything special in your code?

Comment: No i haven't changed anything. I can still deploy it on my computer but when I want to create a app package I get a build error.

Comment: What happens when you clean and rebuild your solution Does it still run? And what about in release version does your app still run on your computer?

Comment: What is the error? Maybe is something not related to the code

Comment: Have you checked the build version for .NET native for every platform?

Comment: Have you tried changing target to 64bit or x86 and not to Any CPU?

Comment: I solved the problem. When you want to make a app package and you haven't set the logos for the app, it won't make a package. I was confused because it said that my custom control cannot be found but that failure wasn't comming after I set the logos.